# Swift with ios-charts library,How to set the size of icons above bars in BarChart?

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, ios-charts

using Charts library, I have a view with shows image or initials of a name up to data inserted. I'd like to use this view as image on top of bars. Since it is not an age, I have to convert it to UIImage via a custom method, since Icon does not accept Views bu only images.

If I try to change frames values I cannot get why I want, the round view being a bit smaller, in this case just the same size of bars, and not "decentered".

left: starting situation (circle is slightly bigger than bar's width)
right: after changing I.E. width and high to 52

[image]

my custom view has this code I think could be useful here (cannot change given intrinsicContentSize):

```
public var model: BrandViewModel! { didSet { self.updateOutlets() } }
open override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize { CGSize(width: 72, height: 72) }


open override func configure() {
    
    super.configure()
    
    self.backgroundColor = .white
    self.layer.cornerRadius = self.intrinsicContentSize.width / 2
    self.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = self.imageView.bounds.width / 2
    self.initialsContainer.layer.cornerRadius = self.imageView.layer.cornerRadius
    
    self.setupShadow()
}
```

My class for the chart:

```
public struct BarChartValue {
    public var value: Double?
    public var name: String?
    public var color: UIColor?
    
    public init(value: Double?, name: String?, color: UIColor?) {
        self.value = value
        self.name = name
        self.color = color
    }
}

public class CorporateBarChartView: BarChartView {
    
    public override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.setup()
    }
    
    public var values: [BarChartValue]? {
        willSet {
            self.setDataCount(withValues: newValue)
        }
    }
    
    private func setup() {
        self.chartDescription.enabled = false
        self.highlightPerTapEnabled = false
        self.legend.enabled = false
        self.drawBarShadowEnabled = false
        self.drawValueAboveBarEnabled = false
        self.leftAxis.enabled = false
        self.rightAxis.enabled = false
        self.xAxis.enabled = false
        self.pinchZoomEnabled = false
        self.doubleTapToZoomEnabled = false
        self.leftAxis.axisMinimum = 0
        self.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    }
    
    func setDataCount(withValues values: [BarChartValue]?) {
        guard let values = values else { return }
        let silverPlaceholder = UIColor.gray.withAlphaComponent(0.2)
        
        let dataEntries = values.enumerated().map({ (index, value) -> BarChartDataEntry in
            let brandView = BrandView()
            brandView.model = BrandViewModel(name: value.name, image: nil)
            let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 72, height: 72))
            view.addSubview(brandView)
            view.backgroundColor = .red//.clear
            brandView.backgroundColor = .green//.clear
            let image = self.image(with: view)
            return BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(index), y: value.value ?? 0, icon: image)
        })
        var set: BarChartDataSet! = nil
        set = BarChartDataSet(entries: dataEntries)
        set.colors = values.map({ (model) -> NSUIColor in
            return (model.color ?? silverPlaceholder)
        })
        set.drawValuesEnabled = false
        
        let data = BarChartData(dataSet: set)
        data.barWidth = 0.3
        self.data = data
    }
    
    func image(with view: UIView) -> UIImage? {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, false, 0.0)
        defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }
        if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
            view.layer.render(in: context)
            let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            return image
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Why do you have to wrap your `brandView` into another `view`? If you do that, then you have to make sure that it is properly laid out or a proper frame is set. I'd also recommend to reuse one instance of the view meaning I'd create it once before dataEntries and reconfigure it with a new data to generate a new image.
2. I guess you have to resize the image to the required size so the chart can draw it properly. For that you can use these extensions:

```
extension UIImage {

    func scaled(toWidth width: CGFloat) -> UIImage? {

        guard width > 0.0, self.size.width > 0.0 else {
            return nil
        }

        return self.redrawnImage(with: self.size.scaled(toWidth: width))
    }

    func scaled(toHeight height: CGFloat) -> UIImage? {

        guard height > 0.0, self.size.height > 0.0 else {
            return nil
        }

        return self.redrawnImage(with: self.size.scaled(toHeight: height))
    }

    private func redrawnImage(with size: CGSize) -> UIImage {

        UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: size).image { _ in
            draw(in: .init(origin: .zero, size: size))
        }
    }
}

extension CGSize {

    func scaled(toWidth width: CGFloat) -> CGSize {
        CGSize(width: width, height: (self.height / self.width) * width)
    }

    func scaled(toHeight height: CGFloat) -> CGSize {
        CGSize(width: (self.width / self.height) * height, height: height)
    }
}
```

Comment: hi, sorry but code is not all my own, not sure how I could use your methods, maybe this way?           'let image = self.image(with: view)?.scaled(toWidth: 50)?.scaled(toHeight: 50)'

Comment: tested this solution, but is not dynamically adaptive to screen sizes. is there a way to set Icons sizes above the bars?

Comment: `let image = self.image(with: view)?.scaled(toWidth: 50)` would return you an image with 50pt width and height that will be matching the ratio of the image.
You never said anything about dynamically adapting it to the screen size. Look inside of the charts library, maybe there's a way to get the width of the bar. And then according to this width you can rescale your image.